# PostgreSQL: SELECT INTO is changing a field's data type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo_raw
(
    time   TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    volume INTEGER,                  <-- note source field is of type integer
    price  DOUBLE PRECISION
);
```

I am populating it from a csv file:

```
COPY foo_raw(time,volume,price) FROM 'raw_data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

I then do a `SELECT INTO` a new table where I am merging duplicate `time` rows into a total volume and volume-weighted average price.

**`SELECT INTO`:**

```
SELECT
    time, 
    SUM(volume)::integer AS volume,          <-- note typecast to integer here
    SUM(volume * price) / SUM(volume) AS price
INTO
    foo
FROM
    foo_raw
GROUP BY
    time
ORDER BY
    time;
```

If I describe my new table, I see that the `volume` field is of type `numeric`, not `integer`.

```
pg=# \d foo
                   Table "public.foo"
 Column |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 time   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 volume | numeric                  |           |          |     
 price  | double precision         |           |          |
```

**Typecasting:**

You'll note above in my `SELECT INTO` statement I have tried to typecast the result of `SUM(volume)` to integer, but that is not working either.

**Question**

How can I force the field to be of type `integer`?

Comment: Unrelated, but: The standard `create table as select` is preferred over the proprietary `select .. into ..` (but that won't solve your problem)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html) changes the data type of numbers to larger values, so it doesn't add up to a number that overflows:

> bigint for smallint or int arguments, numeric for bigint arguments, otherwise the same as the argument data type

Comment: so my typecast to integer has no effect?

Comment: I tried it with the cast and both the "select into" syntax and "create table as ..." syntax, and both made a table with integer in it.

Comment: That is really weird - I'm convinced I was seeing a different result...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Cast it as an integer with sum(volume)::integer like so:

```
 SELECT
     time, 
     SUM(volume)::integer AS volume, 
 here
     SUM(volume * price) / SUM(volume) AS price
 INTO
     foo
 FROM
     foo_raw
 GROUP BY
     time
 ORDER BY
   time;
```

If you're truly concerned about the data types of the result set, I'd cast every single column appropriately.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I'm already doing, and it's not working? What am I missing?